# "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'firebase/app'. Relative references must start with either '/', './', or '../'"

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack

I'm encountering an error in my JavaScript project and I'm seeking help to resolve it. When running my application, I receive the following error message in the browser console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'firebase/app'. Relative references must start with either '/', './', or '../'"

The error occurs when I try to import the 'firebase/app' module in my JavaScript file. Here's the import statement causing the error:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
```

This import is coming from the entry index.js file.

Here are some details about my project setup:

I'm using Webpack as my bundler.
I have a src folder where I keep my source files, and a dist folder where the bundled JavaScript file is generated.
I'm using the Firebase JavaScript SDK and have installed it as a dependency in my project.

[image]

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Checked the import path: I've verified that the import path for the Firebase module is correct and matches the installed package.

Ensured the Firebase package is installed: I have confirmed that the Firebase package is installed in my project's package.json file.

Verified the bundling process: I've reviewed my Webpack configuration to ensure that it correctly bundles the JavaScript files and outputs the bundled file to the dist folder.

Despite these checks, I'm still unable to resolve the error. It's worth noting that the error doesn't occur when I run the application by directly opening the index.html file in the dist folder.

Could someone please help me understand the cause of this error and guide me on how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which file is the `import` statement in? Which file is your Webpack entry point?

Comment: `@firebase/app`?

Comment: @msbit nope ~ https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize